# jquery select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, while-loop

I am building a loop to fetch all the rows from my database and output them into rows for a table.

I am adding a select all checkbox at the header of the table when checked, it selects all, when unchecked, it deselects all.

I cant get it to work for some reason if someone can show me support.

```
           <div class="table">
        <div class="table-head">
            <div class="column" data-label="select"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall">Select all</input></div>
            <div class="column" data-label="id">ID</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="avatar">Avatar</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="username">Username</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="email">Email</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="active">Active</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="level">Level</div>
            <div class="column" data-label="modify">Modify</div>
        </div>

        <?php
$request = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users'); 
while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="select"><input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" value="' . $table['id'] . '" onclick="resetSelectAll();" /></div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="id">' . $table['id'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="avatar"><img src="uploads/' . $table['profile_image'] . '" alt=""></div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="username">' . $table['username'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="email">' . $table['email'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="active">' . $table['active'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="level">' . $table['user_level'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="column" data-label="modify"><a href="edit.php"><img src="images/tool.png" alt=""></a>  <a href="delete.php"><img src="images/delete.png" alt=""></a></div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
        ?>

    </div>
```

my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
 $('#selectall').on('click', function() {
    $('.selectedId').attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
</script>
```

does anyone notice a problem?

here is a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44g8stk7/1/

Comment: use .prop() `$('.selectedId').prop('checked', this.checked);`

Comment: Same issue, still doesnt select all, thanks for the assistance. @ArunPJohny

Comment: can you share the generated html?... also whether any of the checkboxes are getting checked

Comment: None of them are getting checked. I can give you the code in js fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/44g8stk7/1/ @ArunPJohny

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7uannp0z/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I dont notice what you updated in the code. I relocated the javascript tho so it combines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60360/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-brian-cherdak).